# Eight different dolls are to be packed with a condition

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Eight different dolls are to be packed  in eight different boxes. If two of the boxes are too small to hold five of the dolls, in how many ways can the dolls be packed? I tried to solve it, but got confused.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get confused? Provide more details please rather then simply asking for an answer.

Comment: Is it one doll per box, but five of the dolls are large and two of the boxes are small; or is it that a small box can't hold five at the same time?

Comment: This is not a probability question.  You are counting arrangements, so it is a combinatorics question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Eight different dolls are to be packed in eight different boxes. If two of the boxes are too small to hold five of the dolls, in how many ways can the dolls be packed?

I'll assume this means that every doll goes into a unique box.

We can find this number using [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle):

1. We include all $8!$ permutations of the dolls into boxes.
2. We exclude the [???] permutations where small-box-1 gets a too-big doll.  We also exclude the [???] permutations where small-box-2 gets a too-big doll.
3. We then re-include the [???] permutations where small-box-1 and small-box-2 get a too-big doll.

This gives [???] permutations.  We can verify this using the [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) code

```
Number(PermutationsList([1..8]),i->not (i[1] in [1..5] or i[2] in [1..5]));
```

by labeling the too-small boxes 1 and 2, and the too-big dolls 1 through 5.

Spoiler alert:

> We exclude $5 \cdot 7!$ twice (choosing one of the too-small boxes, and putting in it one of the 5 too-big dolls; the remainder are filled arbitrarily), and we re-include $5 \cdot 4 \cdot 6!$ (choosing both of the two-small boxes, and putting in them two of the too-big dolls; the remainder are filled arbitrarily).  This gives $8!-2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7! + 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 6!=4320$.

Comment: What you want to mean about too -big doll , please explain. This is problem where one can't fit more than 4 dolls on a small boxe . I can't understand why you assume that every doll goes on to a unique box . Please explain

Comment: By saying 'two of the boxes are too small to hold five of the dolls' they meant that two particular boxes are too small to contain any of perticular 5 balls. And yes every ball must go to unique box as ' Eight different dolls are to be packed in eight different boxes'  statement implies so.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $A_1, A_2,..,A_8 $ are the boxes where $b_1,b_2,..,b_8$ are the balls. Moreover $A_1$ and $A_2$ are too small to hold balls  $b_1,b_2,..,b_5$. Then, these $5$ balls goes to other $6$ boxes i.e. $A_3, A_4,..,A_8 $ in $6*5*4*3*2 = 720$ ways. Now there are $3$ balls left and $3$ boxes left. These balls can be arranged in $3! = 6$ ways. Hence total number of ways to arrange the balls is $720*6= 4320$